# Python bokeh callback function slider

Tags: python, slider, bokeh

Can someone explain, why this doesn't do anything and how I can print values from inside the callback function? Problem must lay in the callback function. I want my plot to be updated by the date range slider in a standalone html file, but nothing happens, when I change the values of the slider.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, DatetimeTickFormatter, HoverTool
from bokeh.models.widgets import DateRangeSlider
from bokeh.layouts import layout, column
from bokeh.models.callbacks import CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, save

datesX = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-02', periods=100)
# valuesY = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,25,size=(100, 1)), columns=list('A'))
np.random.seed(0)
valuesY  = np.random.rand(100)

source = ColumnDataSource(data={'x': datesX, 'y': valuesY}) 

# output to static HTML file
output_file('file.html')

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Timestamp', '@x{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'), ('Value', '@y')], formatters={'@x': 'datetime'})
    
date_range_slider = DateRangeSlider(title="Zeitrahmen", start=datesX[0], end=datesX[99], \
                                        value=(datesX[0], datesX[99]), step=1, width=1000)

# create a new plot with a title and axis labels
p = figure(title='file1', x_axis_label='Date', y_axis_label='yValue',  x_axis_type='datetime', 
               tools="pan, wheel_zoom, box_zoom, reset", plot_width=1000, plot_height=700)

# add a line renderer with legend and line thickness
    
p.line(x='x', y='y', source=source, line_width=2)
p.add_tools(hover)
       
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var data = source.data;
    var a = cb_obj.value;
    var xmin = a[0];
    var xmax = a[1];
    var x = data['x'];
    var y = data['y'];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (data['x'][i] == xmin){
            startidx = i;       
        }
        if (data['x'][i] == xmax){
            endidx = i;
        }
    }
    
    int j=0;
    while(j <= endidx-startidx){
        x[j] = data['x'][startidx+j];
        y[j] = data['y'][startidx+j];
        j++;
    }

    source.change.emit();
    """)
    
date_range_slider.js_on_change('value', callback)
layout = column(p, date_range_slider)

# show the results
show(layout)
```

Answer (score 0):

When developing JS callbacks, it is essential to learn how to view your browser's JavaScript console. This differs by browser so you will have to search how to access the console on whatever specific browser you are using.

Once you can see the console, you will see that your code has an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'j'

because you have `int j` instead og `var j` in your callback code. It that is fixed, there is then another error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: endidx

It's not really clear what you you actually want to happen, so it's not really possible to try to actually fix the code completely, but hopefully this gives you the information you need to properly do the debugging yourself. Some other tips for debugging:

- to "print" in console, use `console.log(...)`
- you can also add the command `debugger` in the callback code. If you run the Bokeh script with `BOKEH_MINIFIED=no` and the browser dev tools window open, then the exectution will stop at that point and you can single step through the code.

Comment: aaah finally someone to talk to :) thank you very much for your answer!!! I want to adjust the data in my plot. The DateRangeSlider should set the limits of the plotted data. When I set the Limit higher than the starting value, the data points to this date should vanish.

Comment: Where do I have to open the browsers console? I don't mean the console itself (I'm using Edge, so F12 does the Job), but currently I'm using jupyter notebook for developing, so do I have to open it on that page, or where the html file is opened? I tried both, but it can't even tell me what 'data' is, when I try console.log('data')

Comment: It's the console for whatever browser is displaying the plot. If you actually passing the string literal `'data'` then it will just print the string "data". If I put `console.log(data)` right after the first line `var data ...` then I can see the value in the console.

Comment: hm chrome doesn't show me any information either. I get this warning: main.min.js:55806 actions jupyter-notebook:find-and-replace does not exist, still binding it in case it will be defined later... . maybe there is the problem idk. when I open the console on the notebook page as well on the page with the plot and try to display data, I get: VM39:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Comment: I also executed these lines of codes from the command prompt with the same result